# How to pass params to function on onPress in react native

Tags: react-native, function, parameters

I am new to react native. I want to pass leadTagNumber to function and then to API. so how to pass that leadTagNumber to function. please help.

here is my code

```
  ScreenData () {
    const {navigation} = this.props
        const data = this.props.route.params.data
       const leadTagNumber = this.props.route.params.leadTagNumber
  
  AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"]).then(response => {
        console.log(response[0][1]) // Value1
        console.log(response[1][1]) // Value2
        console.log(leadTagNumber)

   fetch("https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/get_merchant_onboard_data", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify([{ id:response[1][1], application_id:response[0][1], lead_tag_number:leadTagNumber}]),
   })
     .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
       .then((response)  => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response))
      console.log(response)
         {
           this.props.navigation.navigate("FormItems", {
  
           });
          }
     })
     .catch((error) => console.log(error));
   })
   

  render() {
     const data = this.props.route.params.data   
         
         {data.map(item => 

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.ScreenData({leadTagNumber:item.lead_tag_number })}> 
            <Card center middle shadow style={{ height:80, width:"100%" }} >
            <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ paddingRight:190, width:'200%'}}>
                     {item.lead_tag_number}
                     </Text>
                      </Card>
                      </TouchableOpacity>)}
```

please ignore this = I am new to react native. I want to pass leadTagNumber to function and then to API. so how to pass that leadTagNumber to function. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScreenData(leadTagNumber){
   console.log(leadTagNumber)
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.ScreenData(item.lead_tag_number)}>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

pass parameter to function

Comment: what is 5. please

Comment: 5 will be your leadtagnumber you want to pass in parameter

Comment: no But am getting leadTagNumber by mapping array so its more than 2 lead tag number so how to do it

Comment: @SohilShaikh it will be your item.lead_tag_number check answer i have updated

Comment: ya I have try this. but I am getting blank array and in console undefined instead of leadTagNumber

Comment: ohhhhh sorrry sorryr I got the point thanku very much

Comment: thanku You solved It Your are legend life saver thanku

Comment: your welcome @SohilShaikh enjoy coding :)